# How to add a external link in a watchOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos

I have a notes app on the phone. On the watch, I would like the link/URL to open up in to Safari.
Is that possible on watchOS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65517870/3151675